# Asp.net How to limit number of digits before and after the decimal point in textbox keypress event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Gridview with a textbox. How do I limit the number of digits before and after the decimal point in a **textbox keypress event**? I want a maximum of 6 digits before the decimal point and 2 digits after the decimal point.
How do I do this with javascript/JQuery?

Comment: Sounds like an easy enough job for a jQuery input mask plugin: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: Fighting the user input is hard. Users gets frustrated and sometimes you block a valid input. It's better to give proper feedback in the input field and prune the input on blur.

Answer (score 2):

I personally do not like wiping out the data as soon as a user types something.

Instead, I like to display an error message after they finish entering data.

For example,

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" MaxLength="9" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    ValidationExpression="^((\d{5})*|([1-9]\d{0,5}))(\.\d{0,2})?$"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="Input must be 123456.78 format." 
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: I don't want to raise the error. Instead, just limit the length of the digits. Like MaxLength = "6" will stop writing after 6 digits. But for before and after decimal length limitation, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple javascript validation vanilla style check

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/8aCJc/

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="check()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 function check() {
  var check = true;
  var txt = document.getElementById('myInput');
  tmp = txt.value;
  if (tmp && tmp.length > 0) {

    arg = tmp.split('.');
    if (arg && arg.length > 0) {

      check = arg[0].length <= 6;
      if (arg.length > 1 && check) {
        check = arg[1].length <= 2;
      }
    }


  }
  if (!check)
    alert('check failed');

}
```

Comment: I won't to show the validation message. I want to block the number while exceeding the length in keypress event.